# Simple thread queue design pattern jdk1.4

Tags: java

I need to control the amount of concurrent thread's running. I think I need to use a thread pool? Is there a design pattern for this ? I'm using JDK1.4

Comment: JDK1.4 !!!! Please upgrade to JDK1.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were lots of new classes added into the `java.util.concurrent` packages in JDK 5 and 6.

If you can't upgrade, I'd recommend looking for Doug Lea's concurrent JAR and seeing what it offers.